# WordPress widget / plugin....fields not appearing in my widget

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, widgets, input

Trying to create my first plugin. A simple one. It's doing mainly what I want to do except the widget itself in Appearance-->Widgets doesn't display my fields. Wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to make my fields appear?

```
function form($instance) {
    $title = esc_attr($instance['title']); ?>
    <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">
    <?php _e('Title:'); ?>     
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" 
    name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" 
    value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></label></p>
<?php } }
```

Comment: Are you getting errors?  You seem to have an extra }

Comment: No I'm not. Right at the end? Is that where this extra character is?

Comment: I tried to delete the extra } but all that did was make my code invalid. Probably because I had this at the end: add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("thisWidget");'));

Comment: Never ever use `create_function()`, it is a huge security risk and should be avoided ar all times. Use proper closures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code given in OP, it is hard to exactly tell you where you are going wrong. One note on what I can, you should never use `create_function()`, it is a security thread that can be exploited by hackers. You should avoid using that completely. Rather make use of proper [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) that was introduced in PHP 5.3.

To help you, here is a basic skeleton which you can use to build a widget with. Just one note, this requires PHP 5.4 due the the use of the [new short array syntax (`[]`)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

```
class Custom_Services extends WP_Widget 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'widget_custom_service', 
            _x( 'Custom Service Widget', 'Custom Service Widget' ), 
            [ 'description' => __( 'Displays information from a custom service.' ) ] 
        );
        $this->alt_option_name = 'widget_custom_service';

        add_action( 'save_post', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
        add_action( 'deleted_post', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
        add_action( 'switch_theme', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) 
    {
        $cache = [];
        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache = wp_cache_get( 'widget_services', 'widget' );
        }

        if ( ! is_array( $cache ) ) {
            $cache = [];
        }

        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        if ( isset( $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] ) ) {
            echo $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ];
            return;
        }

        ob_start();

        $title          = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Category Posts' );
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/default-widgets.php */
        $title          = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

        // ADD YOUR CUSTOM PHP CODE HERE FOR EXECUTION TO DISPLAY ON FRONT END

        echo $args['after_widget']; 

        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] = ob_get_flush();
            wp_cache_set( 'widget_services', $cache, 'widget' );
        } else {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) 
    {
        $instance                   = $old_instance;
        $instance['title']          = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $this->flush_widget_cache();

        $alloptions = wp_cache_get( 'alloptions', 'options' );
        if ( isset($alloptions['widget_custom_service']) )
            delete_option('widget_custom_service');

        return $instance;
    }

    public function flush_widget_cache() 
    {
        wp_cache_delete('widget_services', 'widget');
    }

    public function form( $instance ) 
    {

        $title      = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>

    <?php
    }

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', function () 
{
    register_widget( 'Custom_Services' );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Took some trial and error but I got it!