# Add featured image to sidebar

Tags: sidebar

I'm working on a custom theme someone else built, and I'm trying to add a featured image to the blog page sidebar, above the widgets. I have already added a featured image to the page sidebar using the following code:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large'); ?>
```

I need to add the same code to whatever template the blog is using, and I can't find it! I've tried index.php with no luck, and I don't see any other template files.

What am I missing??

**EDIT:** 
They created a page called Blog, and set it as a static page in the Reading settings. And I can't figure out which template is displaying these posts.

Comment: Check the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) I hope you will find the template!

Comment: Hi Katie, welcome to WPSE. Please take your time and read [ask]. There are a few confusing/missing parts in your question which makes it hard to understand. When you speak about the blogpage, are you speaking about the page set as posts page when you select a static front page. Please answer this question in the form of an [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying the sidebar or templates itself, why not create a plugin with a widget that does just what you need. This way

- you don't hard code and keeps thing dynamic. This will also allow you to move the widget around at will
- you keep your templates clean, simple and maintainable
- do it the correct way. Stuff like widgets, registering custom post types and taxonomies and shortcodes **should always** be registered in a plugin and not inside a theme

I have written a very basic widget template a while ago which you can check out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183295/31545). We can use this as a basis to create our custom widget. I will comment the parts where you an modify the output. You can also alter the widget as needed.

Lets look at the plugin (*simply create a file in your plugins folder, add this code and activate the plugin*)

***NOTE:*** All code is untested and might be buggy. Also, you will need to have PHP 5.4+ installed for this to work

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Blog Page Featured Image
Plugin URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/219344/31545
Description: Displays the blog page's feaured image in the sidear
Version:     1.0.0
Author:      Pieter Goosen
Author URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen
License:     GPL2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

class Blog_Page_Featured_Image extends WP_Widget 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'widget_blog_page_featured_image', 
            _x( 'Blog Page Featured Image', 'Blog page featured image' ), 
            [ 'description' => __( 'Displays the featured image for the pge set as blog page.' ) ] 
        );
        $this->alt_option_name = 'widget_blog_page_featured_image';

        add_action( 'save_post',    [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
        add_action( 'deleted_post', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
        add_action( 'switch_theme', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) 
    {
        $cache = [];
        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache = wp_cache_get( 'widget_bpfi', 'widget' );
        }

        if ( ! is_array( $cache ) ) {
            $cache = [];
        }

        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        if ( isset( $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] ) ) {
            echo $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ];
            return;
        }

        ob_start();

        $title          = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Blog Page Featured Image' );
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/default-widgets.php */
        $title          = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

        // ADD YOUR CUSTOM PHP CODE HERE FOR EXECUTION TO DISPLAY ON FRONT END
        // First make sure this is the page set as blogpage
        if (    'page' === get_option('show_on_front')
             && is_home()
        ) { // We are on the blogpage
            // Get the current page object
            $page_object = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object();

            // Make sure that the current page IS the one set as blogpage
            if ( $page_object->ID === (int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) {
                /**
                 * Now that we are sure we are on the posts page, lets get and display
                 * its featured image. We will also first make sure that we
                 * actually have one set
                 */
                if ( has_post_thumbnail( $page_object->ID ) )
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page_object->ID );
            }
        }

        echo $args['after_widget']; 

        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] = ob_get_flush();
            wp_cache_set( 'widget_bpfi', $cache, 'widget' );
        } else {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) 
    {
        $instance                   = $old_instance;
        $instance['title']          = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $this->flush_widget_cache();

        $alloptions = wp_cache_get( 'alloptions', 'options' );
        if ( isset($alloptions['widget_blog_page_featured_image']) )
            delete_option('widget_blog_page_featured_image');

        return $instance;
    }

    public function flush_widget_cache() 
    {
        wp_cache_delete('widget_bpfi', 'widget');
    }

    public function form( $instance ) 
    {

        $title      = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>

    <?php
    }

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', function () 
{
    register_widget( 'Blog_Page_Featured_Image' );
});
```

What I also like to do is to always completely remove a widget when it is is totally out of context to avoid the sidebar from rendering a blank space when no other widgets are displayed

We can try the same approach as I have described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204107/31545). You can just add this at the bottom of the plugin

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', function ( $sidebars_widgets )
{
    // Return our filter when we are on admin screen
    if ( is_admin() )
        return $sidebars_widgets;

    // Make sure we are not on the blog page, if we are, bail
    if (    'page' === get_option('show_on_front')
         && is_home()
         && $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object_id() === (int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) 
    )
        return $sidebars_widgets;

    /**
     * Widget we need to target. This should be the name/id we used to register it
     *
     * EXAMPLE
     *   parent::__construct(
            'widget_blog_page_featured_image', 
            _x( 'Blog Page Featured Image', 'Blog page featured image' ), 
            [ 'description' => __( 'Displays the featured image for the pge set as blog page.' ) ] 
        );
     *
     */
    $custom_widget  = 'widget_blog_page_featured_image';

    // See if our custom widget exists is any sidebar, if so, get the array index
    foreach ( $sidebars_widgets as $sidebars_key=>$sidebars_widget ) {
        // Skip the wp_inactive_widgets set, we do not need them
        if ( $sidebars_key == 'wp_inactive_widgets' )
        continue;

        // Only continue our operation if $sidebars_widget are not an empty array
        if ( $sidebars_widget ) {
            foreach ( $sidebars_widget as $k=>$v ) {

                /**
                 * Look for our custom widget, if found, unset it from the $sidebars_widgets array
                 * @see stripos()
                 */
                if ( stripos( $v, $custom_widget ) !== false ) 
                    unset( $sidebars_widgets[$sidebars_key][$k] );
            } // endforeach $sidebars_widget
        } // endif $sidebars_widget
    } // endforeach $sidebars_widgets

    return $sidebars_widgets;
});
```

### EDIT

The code above is now tested and working as expected

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! The issue is that my client is against plugins. They want everything hardcoded into this theme. (They built it so there are no updates to worry about.) The way it is currently being done is a text widget with the image link, which displays on the blog page sidebar. But that's not easy for their clients to update, so they want to be able to set the featured image and have it appear there instead of using a widget. I hope I'm making sense!!

Comment: *The issue is that my client is against plugins* Then you need to make him aware that somethings are meant to be done in a plugin and not in a theme. You can simply copy my code into `functions.php` without the plugin header. As for hardcoding the link, I cannot help you as I do not know how your theme looks like. It is always strange that we answer questions telling someone a better and more correct way on how to do things and then the asker still want to go his own, not very correct way. ;-)

Comment: BTW, my method with using the widget is simple. The widget takes care of everything. All your client needs to do is to drag it into the desired sidebar, and they are done. The widget takes care of everything else. It will automatically display the featured image of the blog page on the blog page