# Try to debug a plug-in written by someone else

Tags: plugins, php

My goal is to display my blog page's featured image. I came across a plug-in by Pieter Goosen, who doesn't seem to be currently active here, that does exactly what I want.

I followed instructions and was able to activate the plug-in but I don't see the expected result, which is the blog page featured image displayed in the right sidebar. I'm not a coder, but I can follow instructions so ELI5, as they say.

I an trying to make the following plug-in work on WordPress 5.3.2:

[Blog Page Featured Image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/219344/31545)

Is there something I need to modify in this code? If so, what and how?

Lars

Update: I just discovered it works! This is a great workaround for those looking to get an image onto the blog page and only the blog page.

Comment: do you have a static page as front page, and one of the other static pages set as the blog page?

Comment: Yes, but never mind… I just discovered it works! What happened I have no idea … maybe emptying the cache? Anyway, this is a great workaround for those who want a specific image on the blog page, and only the blog page. Problem solved!